# How to paste in a new line with vim?

Tags: vim, editor

I often have to paste some stuff on a new line in vim. What I usually do is:

```
o<Esc>p
```

Which inserts a new line and puts me in insertion mode, than quits insertion mode, and finally pastes.

Three keystrokes. Not very efficient. Any better ideas?

Comment: 3 keystrokes isn't efficient?

Comment: 1 or 2 would be better :) Why use vim if not for maximal efficiency?

Comment: It also results an extra newline if the copied content ends in a newline.

Comment: @gtd A normal editor works with <Enter><C-V>. Two keystrokes.

Comment: @user4052054 no, that doesn't do the same thing, o/O work wherever you are on the line, in a normal editor you have to get to the beginning or end of line first.  Furthermore, if you're copying a whole line, then the whole thing just becomes one keystroke to insert a line, which is a much more common proposition in coding.

Comment: @gtd You're right, it's three keystrokes, counting the <End> keystroke.

Comment: If you map Enter to o<Esc>, they are two keystrokes, but still clunky...

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Shortly after `:help p` it says:

```
:[line]pu[t] [x]    Put the text [from register x] after [line] (default
                    current line).  This always works |linewise|, thus
                    this command can be used to put a yanked block as
                    new lines.

:[line]pu[t]! [x]   Put the text [from register x] before [line]
                    (default current line).
```

Unfortunately it’s not shorter than your current solution unless you combined it with some keyboard map as suggested in a different answer. For instance, you can map it to any key (even `p`):

```
:nmap p :pu<CR>
```

Comment: I know that, and I use it, but it's not what I'm asking, because sometimes what you're copying just doesn't have any LF in it. If there was a "paste into a new line" command, it would work regardless of the content you're about to paste, so you wouldn't have to think about it.

Comment: Okay, `:pu[t]` will put the text in a new line after the current line, `:pu[t]!` will put the text in a new line before the current line. I will edit my answer accordingly. (Hooray for `:help p`.)

Comment: Not really better than my current solution, but I think it's the best answer to my question.

Comment: While the same number of keystrokes, I think this feels more efficient.  o<Esc>p feels clunky, while this doesn't.

Comment: You can map the command to any key, including p itself: `:nmap p :pu<CR>` Put it in your .vimrc file and off you go :)

Comment: You can also use `[p` to paste on the line before and `]p` to paste on the line after. For more information on the phenomenal `[p` and `]p` issue `:h ]p`.

Answer (score 70):

Options:

1) Use `yy` to yank the whole line (including the end of line character).  `p` will then paste the line on a new line after the current one and `P` (<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>) will paste above the current line.

2) Make a mapping: then it's only one or two keys:

```
:nmap ,p o<ESC>p
:nmap <F4> o<ESC>p
```

3) The function version of the mapping (unnecessary really, but just for completeness):

```
:nmap <F4> :call append(line('.'), @")<CR>

" This one may be a little better (strip the ending new-line before pasting)
:nmap <F4> :call append(line('.'), substitute(@", '\n$', '', ''))<CR>

:help let-register
:help :call
:help append()
:help line()
:help nmap
```

Comment: Well, I guess I'll make a mapping. I was just hoping there might be a standard solution :-/

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @AI: Using the ',p' (',' is mapped as my <Leader>) is the best solution in my opinion. YOu even provided an easy to use function. :) Great!

Answer (score 38):

You can paste a buffer in insert mode using `<C-R>` followed by the name of the buffer to paste. The default buffer is `"`, so you would do

```
o<C-R>"
```

I found that I use `<C-R>"` very often and bound that to `<C-F>` in my vimrc:

```
inoremap <C-F> <C-R>"
```

Comment: This is great because it keeps the indentation correct if the copied line wasn't indented.

Answer (score 36):

This still uses three keystrokes, but I find it easier than Esc:

`o<Alt-p>`

Since you're in insert mode after hitting o, the Alt modifier will allow you to use a command as if you weren't.

Comment: Quite handy way when you try the yank sth you cut inside the line with "d$" in a new line

Comment: Sorry, but this does not keep the indent, it pastes at the beginning of the line, instead.

Comment: Can anyone elaborate this method for mac(no alt)?

Comment: @Lihaonan Your question is from 8 months ago, hopefully you already saw https://stackoverflow.com/q/7501092/5407634

Answer (score 30):

Using this plugin: https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired

`]p` pastes on the line *below*

`[p` pastes on the line *above*

advantages:

- works on all yanked text (word, line, character, etc)
- indents the pasted text to match the indentation of the text
  around it
- 2 keystrokes instead of 3 and much "easier" strokes
- fast

Comment: My favorite too. Might be worth mentioning you do need `tpope/vim-unimpaired` for this to work .

Comment: ah i installed that so long ago i forgot about it.  thanks for the reminder!

Comment: This solution works in spacemacs o.o.b. for me. (fyi spacemacs users)

Comment: this answer deserves to be the the correct one, simple, fast, no need to go through extra hassles. thanks @crogers 

Answer (score 10):

Personally I've nmapped *Enter (CR)*  like this:

```
nmap <CR> o<Esc>k
```

...based on [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_newline_without_entering_insert_mode) Vim Wikia article.

This way I can make newlines directly from normal mode, and combining this with wanting to paste to a newline below I'd do:

```
<CR>jp
```

You could also skip **k** in the nmap above, depending on what functionality you prefer from *Enter*,  so it would just be `<CR>p`.

I've also imapped jj to *Esc*, which would also assist in this case. *Esc* is way too far away from the home row for how significant it is in vim.

Not shorter than the other solutions, but I do think it feels less clunky than some of them, and it has other uses too.

Answer (score 7):

If you wanted to stay in the insert mode, you can do `o ctrl+o p`

- `o` – insert mode and go to the new line
- `ctrl+o` – run a single command
  like in normal mode
- `p` – paste

It's three keystrokes but you stay in insert mode and also `o ctrl+o` is quite fast so I personally treat it as 2.5 keystrokes.

Comment: plus one for 2.5 keystrokes 

Answer (score 5):

If you're copying a whole line then pasting a whole line, use `Y` to yank the line or lines, including line break, in the first place, and `p` to paste. You can also use `V`, which is visual *line* mode, in contrast with plain `v` for visual mode.

Comment: The problem is, sometimes you simply don't want to copy a whole line... I'd like a solution that works whether I've copied ten lines or two words.

Answer (score 3):

I have mapping `inoremap jj <ESC>`. So it is easy to insert new line with `ojj` and `Ojj` and then `p`.

so `ojjp` paste new a newline. it have one more stroke then `o<esc>p` but `ojjp` is easy for me.

Answer (score 2):

I found an elegant solution to this.  If you are putting the yank register in your OS's clipboard (which is great anyway), with

```
set clipboard+=unnamed
```

than you can do `o<Ctl-v>`.

Besides being fewer strokes, this improves on both `o<Esc>p` and `:pu` because it preserves indenting: both of the other options start you at character zero on the new line.

Caveat is that this may or may not be OS dependent.  All I know is that it works on recent version of OS X, but clipboard is just one of many ways to get yank in the OS clipboard.

Comment: Please be aware that the correct syntax is `o<C-V>`, not `o<Ctl-v>`

Answer (score 2):

I use the following mapping in my Neovim config:

```
nnoremap <leader>p m`o<ESC>p``
nnoremap <leader>P m`O<ESC>p``
```

A little explanation:

- `` m` ``: set a mark in the current cursor position.
- `o<Esc>p`: create a new line below and paste the text in this line
- `O<Esc>P`: create a new line above and paste the text in this line
- ``` `` ```: put the cursor in the original position

See `:h mark` for more information about marks in Vim.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to paste in a `new line` and still keep indentation, create this mapping:

`nnoremap <leader>p oq<BS><Esc>p`

Prerequisite: you have leader mapped and you have `set autoindent` in your `.vimrc`.

Explanation: a new line is created with 'o', 'q' is typed and then back-spaced on (to keep indentation), and 'esc' brings you back to normal mode where you finally paste.

Answer (score 1):

If you also want to end in insert mode, it is possible to paste while in insert mode using `CTRL-R "`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2861909/461834

Still three keystrokes, but no escape, and you save a keystroke if you want to end in insert anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This solution only seems to apply when the block of copied text starts on a new line (as opposed to grabbing a snippet of text somewhere within a line), but you can always start your copy on the last character you want to grab, then navigate to the last character at the end of line prior to the start of your desired copy block.  Then when you want to paste it, place the cursor at the end of the line under which you want your text to be pasted and hit p.  If I haven't screwed up the explanation, this should provide the effect you're looking for.