# How do I paste?

Tags: vim, paste

How do I paste while in paste mode on `vim`? This shouldn't be that hard to find but it isn't explained in any of the tutorials or wikis. I'm trying to paste a block of code while in **PASTE MODE** but I get an error every time I try. I have `F10` mapped to paste toggle.

I tried <kbd>F10</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>, to paste the unnamed register, but that didn't work.

<kbd>F10</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, to paste register a,

and <kbd>F10</kbd><kbd>CTRL-v</kbd>, to paste the clipboard, and even that didn't work.

How do I paste in paste mode?

Comment: Not exactly "PASTE MODE", but it should allow you to paste into vim http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861627/vim-paste-in-insert-mode While in insert mode hit `CTRL-R {register}`. For example, `CTRL-R *` will insert in the contents of the clipboard and `CTRL-R "` (the unnamed register) inserts the the last delete or yank. To find this in vim's help type `:h i_ctrl-r`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vim - paste in insert mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861627/vim-paste-in-insert-mode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use many times <kbd>CTRL-SHIFT-v</kbd> to paste content from the clipboard to `vim` in insert mode with `:set paste` instruction executed just before.

Comment: Oh, definitly easier than "+p, nice! :)