# Vim: paste before cursor in insert mode

Tags: vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vim - paste in insert mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861627/vim-paste-in-insert-mode)

I have, among others, two mappings:

```
vnoremap <C-X> "+x
inoremap <C-V> <C-O>"+P
```

Using that I can select and insert text like in any other editor, but one thing is weird: when the cursor is at the line end, text is being inserted before the last character, not after the last one as expected. Assuming the clipboard contains `x`. Cursor is at `|`. In Insert mode:

```
^|ab$   yields: ^x|ab$   expected: ^x|ab$
^a|b$           ^ax|b$             ^ax|b$
^ab|$           ^axb|$             ^abx|$
```

When I change the mapping to `<C-O>"+p` I have the same problem at line start, I guess this is due to the `<C-O>` which changes the cursor to a block cursor that can't be placed before start/after end.

So: how can I insert text before the insert mode cursor, using `<C-V>`, without having to call a function that calls `p` or `P` depending on the position in the line, which would be the only thing I can think of?

Answer (score 1):

[First related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861627/vim-paste-in-insert-mode). Duh.

```
inoremap <C-V> <C-R>"
```

Inserts contents of register `"` before the cursor in insert mode just like I wanted it.