# vim: left align consecutive lines with the current line

Tags: vim, indentation

Often times when I paste into vim I get cascading indents that are quite frustrating to fix.  The result will look something like this

```
This is line one
    This is line two
        This is line three
            This is line four
```

I'd like to know if there is a way that I could tell vim to align lines two through four with line one.  If line one text is starting at cursor position 6 is there a way to say "make the next ten lines also start at position 6?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vim - paste in insert mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861627/vim-paste-in-insert-mode)

Comment: Take a look at `:h paste` and `:h pastetoggle` for pasting into vim. Cheers!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To correct this cascading indentation, you can re-indent a block using `=`. Select a visual block and type `=` or supply a motion: `=4j` to re-indent the next 4 lines.

You might avoid the cascading indentations by setting `paste` before pasting: `:set paste`. After the paste `:set nopaste`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `:set paste` to avoid this when pasting in text.  And you can set the indent level for a range with `left`.

```
:<range>left3
```

E.g.

```
.,+4left3
```

Will set the indent of the next 4 lines to 3.

Note:  Range can be defined in visual mode, just select some lines with `S-v` and then press `:left4`

Answer (score 2):

Before pasting, do `:set paste`, after pasting, do `:set nopaste`.

Or use Vim's built-in paste commands with the clipboard register:

```
"+p (paste after the cursor or below the line)
"+P (paste before the cursor or above the line)
```

See `:help 'paste'` and `:help registers`.