# nmap to simulate shift-insert in insert mode

Tags: vim

In vim I would like to create a key map for `gp` in normal mode so that it switches to insert mode and simulate the `shift+insert` key press and goes back to normal mode.

here is what I tried:

`nmap gp i<S-Insert><esc>`

All it does is insert the text `<S-Insert>` instead of pressing executing shift+insert.

I've looked at [Paste in insert mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861627/paste-in-insert-mode) but the I can't get the contents of what I'm pasting from a buffer.

Comment: What are trying to do? Why not just paste in normal mode?

Comment: `gp` is a bit ergonomic to type than shit+insert.  I also intend to do `:set paste` and `:set nopaste` to allow pasting code

Answer (score 1):

You have to enter the control characters directly. You do this by pressing `<C-V><Wanted Character>` in insert mode.

For more on this see `i_CTRL-V`.

Comment: have you tried setting `<shift+insert>` in this way?  It doesn't work for me.