# How to paste the content without auto-indentation in Vim?

Tags: vim

I've used Ctrl+Shift+v to paste in Ubuntu 14.04, but after I've updated my ubuntu and vim it automatically inserts the indentation when I past texts through ctrl+shift+v.

I found that automatic indentation can be turned off/on by entering **set paste / set nopaste** or map the key for pastetoggling (**set pastetoggle= < F2 >**) in the .vimrc file.

However, I am too lazy to push the pastetoggling key (F2), and tried [clime's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861627/paste-in-insert-mode), but it seems not to be working.

First, for the above approach, it seems that shift doesn't make any difference, for example < C-V > and < C-S-V > cannot map two different keys. How can I remap the < C-S-V > in vimrc?

Second, I've found one trick [in this blog](https://coderwall.com/p/if9mda/automatically-set-paste-mode-in-vim-when-pasting-in-insert-mode), but cannot understand how it works. What kind of background is necessary to understand the details of it?

Comment: The blog you point to is **the answer**. I've been using this for a few years now and quite satisfied with the results. You need to know [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), especially **bracketed paste mode**.

Comment: @phd Thanks for a comment. By the way, why vimrc cannot discern differences between < c-s-v > and < c-v > and < c-V> etc?

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply trying to remap toggling paste/nopaste, you can do that with the ! operator. In the .vimrc that would look like:

`nnoremap <your remap> :set paste!<cr>`