# "M-" bindings in vim on iTerm2/Terminal don't work

Tags: vim, osx-lion, iterm

I noticed that [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/) offers the very convenient feature of using "Option key as +ESC" (or as meta, but apparently that's obsolete).

I tried them both and the option key works as expected in Bash (`set -o emacs` mode) and Emacs, but not in Vim. Thus, I can't make use of any "M-" bindings.
What I've found is that:

- if I set option to "+ESC", vim just understands ESC+key, and has no idea I actually meant Meta-key.
- if I set option to "meta", keys modified with "option" behave just as without a modifier (don't know how to formally test what vim understands from a key combination that I'm typing).

"M-" mappings work perfectly in MacVim (7.3.53), but that's outside of a console and not in the scope of this question.

I'm interested in how to make those mappings work in Vim, under iTerm2 or Terminal.

**My specs**:

- MAC OS X Lion 10.7.2
- iTerm2 1.0.0.20111020
- vim @7.3.107_0+python26 [though MacPorts]

Comment: Sometimes people use the term "Meta" with a very narrow interpretation to mean "an ASCII character with the high bit set"; however, more generally "Meta" can mean either using the high bit or prefixing with ESC. I assume from the wording that "Option as Meta" specifically means "set the high bit", which is incompatible with using a UTF-8 (or other 8-bit) encoding. Modern terminal emulators generally default to UTF-8 and require using the ESC prefix for "Meta". Mac OS X Terminal's "option as meta key" option only means "prefix with ESC".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15399297/2355112 has the solution on mapping "Option+char" in Mac.

Answer (score 10):

I've downloaded the latest iTerm2 and tried to see what it sent to/what was printed by Vim (`i<C-v><M-a>`) with the following settings:

- **Option as Option:**

  Vim prints `æ` which is normal and expected on my french keyboard
- **Option as Meta:**

  Vim stays there, waiting for something to happen. Nothing is printed. If I press Option and `a` in sequence I just obtain `a`. Pressing Option and `a` in some random order may print `á`, which is weird and totally unexpected.
- **Option as +ESC:**

  Vim prints `^[a` which means "Escape character followed by the character a".

From these tests it appears that Vim will never ever receive `<M->` without some hypothetical black magic.

If you stick with *"Option as +ESC"*, it seems that you will have to change all your custom `<M-something>` mappings to `<Esc>something`. This may work but it will make writing any kind of prose in any non-english language a pain.

What I do: I leave the Option key as it is so that I can type characters like `œ…«»` easily and I use `<Leader>` (mapped to `,`, see `:help mapleader`) for all my custom mappings.

Some people here like to reserve it for plugins and advocate a somewhat simpler and potentially safer approach.

```
inoremap <leader>, <C-x><C-o> "my way (copied elsewhere)
inoremap ,, <C-x><C-o>        "another way
```

Comment: Precisely. Vim never gets any sort of `<M->` combination. The problem is that there are several plugins I use that have `M-` bindings, and it's inconvenient to mess with the plugins. Maybe there's a vim patch to trick it into converting a really fast `Esc+key` into `<M-key>`?

Comment: Also I'd like to map something like `<M-j>` and `<M-k>` to do what `Alt+(up|down)` does in Eclipse (i.e. move line/lines past the line above/below). If I were to map `Esc+(j|k)` instead, then it would be a pain when I exit insert mode and genuinely press one of those movement keys...

Comment: Could you list the plugins that need `<M->`?

Comment: I have `nnoremap <leader>j` and `nnoremap <leader>k` in my `~/.vimrc`. Vim is not Eclipse or Notepad++ or TextMate: you can't just import all your habits like that. Your muscle memory has to be re-trained to work effectively with it. It sure has a cost.

Comment: LaTeX-Suite (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=475) for instance. Sure, but the problem is that stuff that should work doesn't. Why can bash and emacs use Meta, but not vim?

Comment: I'm not sure, see `:help map-alt-keys`: it looks like Vim may be a little limited on that front.

Answer (score 5):

I left my option key to act as Normal and discovered that Vim saw them as `<T-` bindings. So, for example, I have this mapping setup in my .vimrc to move to the end of a word when in Insert mode:

```
noremap! <T-Right> <C-o><Right>;
```