# MacVim (iterm2/tmux) bind alt/meta

Tags: macos, vim, macvim

I have this nice set of vim mappings

```
" Drag Current Line/s Vertically
nnoremap <M-j> :m+<CR>
nnoremap <M-k> :m-2<CR>
inoremap <M-j> <Esc>:m+<CR>
inoremap <M-k> <Esc>:m-2<CR>
vnoremap <M-j> :m'>+<CR>gv
```

that I can't get to work on Mac/iTerm2/Tmux/vim combo. The problem I guess is in Alt key not getting mapped.

P.S. "Left option key acts as" is set to `+Esc` in iTerm session keys preferences

Comment: I can at least confirm this does not work for me with OSX10.6/iTerm2/tmux/vim over ssh (from putty), but DOES work for me with WindowsXP/GVim.

Comment: So that didn't make sense - as in that setup _putty_ would be my terminal, not iTerm2. I do have iTerm2 running at home, but that wouldn't have been part of my test.

Answer (score 5):

I'm throwing this up here after scouring through tons of SO questions and answers. This solution worked for me with iTerm2 + Mojave.

1. In **iTerm2**, go to Preferences -> Profile -> Keys. In the bottom right, change your left (or right) option key to fire off an Esc+ sequence instead of Meta/Normal.
2. Put the following code in your .vimrc:

```
execute "set <A-j>=\ej"
execute "set <A-k>=\ek"

nnoremap <A-j> :m .+1<
nnoremap <A-k> :m .-2<
inoremap <A-j> <Esc>:m .+1<CR>==
inoremap <A-k> <Esc>:m .-2<CR>==
vnoremap <A-j> :m '>+1<CR>gv=
vnoremap <A-k> :m '<-2<CR>gv=gv
```

**What is this doing?**

Admittedly, my understanding is not great. When you send an `ALT+j` command to Terminal, iTerm will receive it as `^[j` which is an Escape sequence. When mapping it to Vim, `^[` ends up as `\e`. If you want to double check what your `ALT+j` (or `ALT+k`) is firing as, type `sed -n l` in a Terminal window and then hit `ALT+j` – you should see this output: `^[j`

The `execute set` commands are remapping `<A-j>` and `<A-k>` mappings for Vim to fire off `^[j`/`^[k` respectively to match what's being fired by iTerm.

This fixed it for me and I can now move line blocks like a pro. Hopefully it helps some people (sorry for my lackluster explanation–still learning the Vim ecosystem).

Answer (score 1):

I've already done [some real life tests regarding this exact issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8224269/546861). My temporary and non-authoritative conclusion was/is that mappings using `<M->` don't work in iTerm2 and that one should use alternative solutions instead.

I use `<leader>`.

Comment: I just tried it without iTerm2. SSHing with putty to OSX10.6 in a tmux session, vim will not allow the mappings. This should effectively eliminate iTerm2 as the culprit.

Comment: Your question and the other one are both about Vim in iTerm2 but the culprit is Vim that doesn't work well with the Meta key *as sent by the shell*.

Answer (score 0):

People asking that question over SO tend to forget not everyone uses US keyboard layout. For 'Polski' I didn't find solution yet, and this is tricky.
I had to set left Option key for esc+ otherwise left and right Options are used for diacritic characters and now `sed -n l` shows for option-j `^[j` and for option-k `^[k` BUT in vim no character is shown - it behaves simply like normal j and k. That being said in iTerm2 preferences window pressing option-j and option-k gives `∆` and `Ż`. so fields in settings respects system keyboard layout while content of the iTerm window is set for UTF-8. Not sure if that has anything to do with it but Alt/Option on Mac is used to insert characters using hexcodes.

Also, iTerm documentation explicitly states that sending <A- is not supported, only <M-. - but I tested both keybindings <A- and <M- in vim and keymapings simply don't work so @LMulvey solution is not valid in 2024.

But after struggling few hours (which indicates itself how bad idea is trying to use terminal editors on Mac - adding tmux to the mix is a nightmare) I accepted it won't work and I'll be using more VSC and Sublime Text where shortcut `<ctrl-command-down>` `<ctrl-command-up>` are set by default and work out of the box