# How to disable generating special characters when pressing the `alt+a`/`option+a` keybinding in Mac OS (`⌥+a` )?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, macos-big-sur

There is a behavior in my mac that I'm trying to disable.

When I'm in any text editor and typing a key combination using the `alt`/`option`+any letter, the output will be special characters.

*For example:*
the combination `alt+a` will generate `å`.
the combination `alt+x` will generate `≈`.

I want to cancel this behavior.
I'm a programmer and when I use my code editor I want to map some keybinding (keyboard shortcuts) to the `alt` key (`⌥+a` for example) but when I do that it doesn't execute because it generates the special characters.
I guess that the special character has a priority over my code editor shortcuts.

Do you know how can I disable this default behavior?

Thank you

Comment: what is your app doing?  if you want to disable option keys in an application where the user is typing in text, your International users are going to be very unhappy with you and your app.  Or is this for a game or is the window / view doing something else?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ and I would like to simulate emacs keyboard shortcuts and I mapped meta to option key.  But when I press, say, option-b, I did get the expected behavior as it is interpreted as a special character.

Comment: If I use option key as a modifier, I can define even more shortcuts in my IDE, which sugnificantly boosts my productivity.

Comment: It's simply ridiculous how hard are such simple actions on Macs. Placed a wrong app in launcher - good luck removing it with SQL statements; want to disable some stupid shortcut - start downloading and testing zillion solutions which are not consistent across OS versions. God, why did I buy this awful computer?

Comment: This works for me : http://superuser.com/a/942256/535138

Comment: For people having problem on terminal, follow this instruction -> https://superuser.com/questions/496090/how-to-use-alt-commands-in-a-terminal-on-os-x

Comment: This is an essence of Apple solutions. Shiny and unusable for anything Apple did not think of.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I was having the exact same problem, in the exact same IDE.

The solution to this is to download Ukulele from here:

http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele

In the application you can create a new keylayout using File -> New from current source. Pressing *Option* will show you in the place for Option-b a red colored key - meaning it's a *dead key*. Double clicking it will allow you to change it from a dead key to an output key. When prompted for the output you can put in the same thing (by pressing Option-b).

Thus it will output the same character but will not be considered a dead key, so Intellij can bind it as a shortcut.

To enable your new layout you must save it into your *~/Library/Keyboard Layouts* (it helps if you give it a new name with Keyboard -> Set Keyboard Name), and then enable it from System Preferences -> Language & Text.

Comment: This is a lot of work and only fixes one key combo in one app. I and at least some others would want to across the board disable opt as special characters input on mac.

Comment: @javadba It wasn't that bad after I got it right. See my answer below for detailed steps which should be fast to click through.

Comment: [I added an answer with detailed steps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24100077/1148030) to what @SebastianZaha describes in this answer. I ended up fumbling about a bit to get it done, so hopefully it will save someone (and later me) some trouble.

Answer (score 97):

You can create a **custom keyboard mapping with option-letters all set to BLANK** using online tool [from this webpage](http://wordherd.com/keyboards/). You can create a custom mapping in several clicks out of almost any keyboard layout. Proved to work on MacOSX 10.7+ with IntelliJ Idea, Php/WebStorm, NetBeans, Eclipse.

Select **"Set blank for option key"** radio in the form, submit the form, and download a patched keyboard layout with "option" key feature disabled. I'm sharing the working file for standard US English keyboard layout:

- [MacOS <= 10.10](https://pelam.fi/osx/USKeylayout_custom_no_alt.keylayout)
- [MacOS >= 10.11](https://gist.github.com/haosdent/573ea124e5ea666fc576)

After enabling this custom mapping, if you type a letter with "option" key pressed, nothing is printed to text output. But, the "option key press" is triggered by OS, and detected by your IDE. So you get exactly the same behaviour as you have for other command keys!

1. Download the key mapping file `My Layout.keylayout`.
2. Move it to `~/Library/Keyboard\ Layouts/`
3. Open `System Preferences` -> `Language Input Methods` (or `Keyboard` -> `Input Sources`)
4. Go to `Input Sources` -> `(hit +)` -> `Select Others`
5. You should find `My Layout` in the list and select it.

*Step 4 can change slightly across MacOS versions. Please be patient to find keyboard layouts list in the settings.*

Comment: I've made some testing and it works on 10.5 also. Usually using it for WebStorm and Idea. This increases the number of hotkeys much!

Comment: works great. Also, for those who would like to further map selected option+... keys to emacs commands, as they work in terminal or linux in general, you may want to check out Emacs Mode under keyremap4macbook.

Comment: I went to the Input Sources Dialog but do not see any layouts list ?  I put the file there   /Users/steve/Library/Keyboard Layouts/BlankOptionKey.keylayout

Comment: @javadba, please try walking around the settings connected with keyboard input. You should find a vertical list with lots of languages supported. I don't have Mac nearby, so I can't give a good answer to your question.

Comment: @Dan  Yes there is a vertical list of languages - but how does that relate to "layouts list"?  There is no "My Layout" there - just .. languages..

Comment: @Dan I found out how to do this - the instructions were missing a step. Should be: keyboard | Input Sources | (hit +) | Select OTHERS (that's the missing step) | (then the "My Layout" shows up)

Comment: @javadba, I've corrected my answer. Thank you for your feedback!! Things could change with new OS versions.

Comment: This seems to work, *however* it also seems to screw up shortcuts for other apps when the custom layout is selected. For example Ctrl-TAB doesn't work on Chrome anymore.

Comment: @JaimeCham strange, this is not connected with `Alt` button

Comment: The dropbox link appears broken now.

Comment: All keys do not work :(

Comment: Oh, I see what's wrong. You did not mention that maybe I should restart the application, like Chrome, to enable the new layout.

Comment: Confirmed working on Yosemite DP5

Comment: I ran into problems with this solution: after disabling the special symbols, I couldn't bind some keys with `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24100077/903943 is working perfectly.

Comment: Could not get this to work. I can add my new key layout to the list, but I cannot remove the default 'US' layout, thus it won't actually use my new key layout....

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me on Yosemite and Mountain Lion. On Yosemite (10.10), adding layouts is in Language & Region, Keyboard Preferences, Input Sources

Comment: Turning on 'Leave Option blank' breaks Ctrl+/ in Emacs for me

Comment: As for me I couldn't make this work on Yosemite: I followed all the instructions successfully, I see that in my browser for example I can not type alt+symbols, but in IDEA just nothing happens when I try to use a shortcut. I'm not sure how, I restarted it, but it seems not to pick up the info that now this key combination is blank and can be triggered as a shortcut.

Comment: This is not work in 10.11 anymore. I generate a layout file in https://gist.github.com/haosdent/573ea124e5ea666fc576 which works in 10.11

Comment: Didn't work for me. Instead of option+r typing `®`, it now types `r` in IntelliJ :(

Comment: same thing here as for @Navin, `option`+letter now prints that letter to text output :(

Comment: Generate from the website, because when I download the file from GitHub, then the characters appear in IntelliJ. Not so when I generate the file myself.

Comment: @tiktak is right! I've just generated one myself using the `Yes, but leave the "option" keystrokes blank.` option, and it works perfectly :)) Thank you!
(@Navin try like this)

Comment: @Navin  Sorry that miss the message, I update my script at https://gist.github.com/haosdent/573ea124e5ea666fc576

Comment: Didnt seem to work.  I have a laptop with a keyboard and an external keyboard.  I wonder if it only changed things for the laptop keyboard not the external one.  Any idea how to change the external one?

Answer (score 54):

Here are detailed steps to Sebastian Zaha's answer. (I ended up fumbling around a bit before I got this working).

(Alternatively [here is a ready made file by me](https://pelam.fi/osx/USKeylayout_custom_no_alt.keylayout))

1. Download [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele)
2. You can run it directly from the .dmg file
3. File -> New Based On Current Input Source (I had US selected)
4. Click Modifiers button
5. Select each modifier from list that have **Left Down** or **Right Down** in the **Option column**. (There could be some like **Either Down OR Up** too, but AFAIK you can leave those.)

   - Press the minus button for each like this
6. Go to Keyboard menu -> Set Keyboard Name
7. Change the name somehow to make it easier to identify
8. Go to File -> Save as
9. Save to ~/Library/Keyboard\ Layouts/ with suffix .keylayout
10. Log out from your Mac OS account
11. Log back in
12. Go to System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Sources
13. Hit the + button -> Others -> Your new layout should be available
14. Add the new layout
15. Possibly leave original keyboard layout too and configure some nice way to switch

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me and allowed me to rebind the key combos to Emacs-like commands.

Comment: @event_jr, how did you rebind them for emacs behaviour?  When you hold down option and click on b,  it asks for output for that combination.  How do we tell it that output is to go back a word?

Comment: @Sahas This answer is about stopping key from interpreted as a special character.  Once you do that, you have to edit DefaultKeyBinding.dict to enable Emacs commands for specific key combos.

Comment: As I commented above this didn't help me to fix shortcuts in IDEA on Yosemite too. I'm afraid they changed something in newer versions and now it became not possible to fix this. I'm running IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.2 on OS X Yosemite 10.10.3

Comment: @Innokenty Strange. I'm on OSX 10.10.3 and IDEA 14.1.2 and my emacs-like bindings work. I brought the IDEA config over from a windows machine and the .keylayout file was built using some older version of OSX. Could one of these be the reason? [Here is my layout file.](http://pelam.fi/osx/USKeylayout_custom_no_alt.keylayout)

Comment: @PeterLamberg Wow, this one works, thank you! Maybe I excluded the modifiers in Ukelele the wrong way. I left the 'Either Down's and 'Either Down OR Up's untouched.

Comment: Also this link might be useful for those that want to remove the default 'U.S.' layout: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44921/how-to-remove-or-disable-a-default-keyboard-layout?newreg=9b119b3cbcbf41f9948b58b551b83865

Comment: @Innokentry Thanks for responding! I'm adding the file to main post too.

Comment: I was also searching for a solution to the option keymapping problem in IntelliJ/10.10.3, and found this. And it worked -  thank you @PeterLamberg! I was previously using cmd-key-happy, now I'm using Karabiner to swap option/command keys, and ctrl-space to select wasn't working until I added your keymap. One thing that was nice about cmd-key-happy is that you could specify 'passthrough' for sequence like cmd-tab for app switching. I could then hit option-tab to do this with cmd-key-happy but now it doesn't appear to do anything. Have you run into an issue like this? Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you! I use Alt+Slash so many times...

Comment: In OS X 10.10.5, I didn't see any "Left Down" or "Right Down" in the "Option" column: just "Either Down". I removed all those, and now have Emacs-style keybindings working in IntelliJ. I wish I understood what removing those rows meant, but since it's easy to switch input methods if I run into trouble, I'm going with it. Thanks.

Comment: @Innokenty If you export the layout as a bundle, then you can simply remove the other layout from preferences. If not working make sure you set script to Latin when saving bundle. Oh and this way you can keep the layout icon too.

Comment: 2022, macOS Monterey:  for some reason it wasn't enough to clear out the modifiers that had option.   I had to explicitly add in a modifier set (with +, only select "option down") at index 0.   Without doing so, for some reason the alt key would trigger some other map at another index.   Doing so seems to explicitly say "when option is pressed, the letters on the keyboard are the same as if option wasn't pressed".

Answer (score 15):

Use `Ctrl-Alt-<MNEMONIC>`. IMHO much easier than having to install and configure a separate app.

Comment: Good to know. However this is not completely satisfactory if also the Ctrl-Alt- key combinations have functions.

Comment: For IDE's CTRL+ALT is likely already used, so you have to reconfigure your IDE, which is equal pain to having to configure some other app.

Comment: this answer is what you get if you ask JetBrains

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue on a new Macbook with VSCode which had worked fine on my old Macbook.  When I typed alt-shift-f for format I got unicode instead.  I realised the difference was my old Macbook had a British keyboard setup instead of the default "ABC - Extended".  Adding the British keyboard fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I tried this but still got an annoying character with Option+N for example in Intellij IDEA.

Comment: I used the keyboard layout "Unicode Hex Input" (under "Others"). It looks Identical to the U.S. layout but with the alt-combos blanked.

Comment: @Coops thanks, that's the only keyboard that worked for me

Comment: this is what worked for me. I had ABC-india selected earlier, changing it to "British" keyboard fixed the options key. version - Ventura 13.5

Answer (score 9):

I have a solution!
Place a file at: `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` as:

```
/* ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict */
 {
    /* Additional Emacs bindings */
    "~f" = "moveWordForward:";
    "~b" = "moveWordBackward:";
    "~<" = "moveToBeginningOfDocument:";
    "~>" = "moveToEndOfDocument:";
    "~v" = "pageUp:";
    "~d" = "deleteWordForward:";
    "~^h" = "deleteWordBackward:";
    "~\010" = "deleteWordBackward:";  /* Option-backspace */
    "~\177" = "deleteWordBackward:";  /* Option-delete */

    /* Escape should really be complete: */
    "\033" = "complete:";  /* Escape */        
}
```

It will hide the original textual input. But you can still get that by using Ctrl-Q before the combination.
So Ctrl-Q Alt-f gives me ƒ for example.
In fact, I'm writing this answer with the option keybindings enabled.
You can also add other keys you like! Official reference:
                      https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TextDefaultsBindings/TextDefaultsBindings.html

Here is a good list of things you can bind to:
https://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/site/selectors.html

Oh, by the way, if you bind a key to an undefined action, your application will have a memory leak and your system will run out of memory in a few seconds. Tested on el capitan, in the hard way.

Answer (score 3):

Use ABC as input method instead of ABC-Extended, then option + [char] would be able to use the application shortcut instead of showing special character.

Comment: This answer helped me, Instead of ABC-Locale or ABC-Extended, I used ABC

Comment: This does not disable special characters in general. I still have a chance of accidentally typing the multibyte dash `–` instead of the ASCII `-`, which could lead to really confusing errors especially in languages with the `->` operator.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Apple JRE, the Option key combinations will work as shortcuts instead of inserting special characters.

Download link:
https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US

It's an old outdated JRE (based on Java 6) but as of October 2015 it's still what seems to work best w/ my JetBrains RubyMine installation.  (Anything else, the keys go back to inserting special characters.)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a decent workaround.
I use the software Karabiner to change my right enter key to control when held down.

So what iv done is remapped the option key to option+cmd+control, as I'm not aware of any commands that use all three modifiers. Now I can map the right shortcuts without any characters. But you could also map to additional keys if required

Add this to your private.xml: (in between root)

```
<item>
<name>Change option Key to cmd + control + option</name>
<identifier>private.optiontoelse</identifier>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ 
    KeyCode::OPTION_L, 
    KeyCode::OPTION_L, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L | ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ 
    KeyCode::OPTION_R, 
    KeyCode::OPTION_R, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_R | ModifierFlag::COMMAND_R</autogen>
</item>
```

Then reload the xml and enable the option at the top of the 'Change Key' tab

https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

Comment: For Karabiner-Elements, which uses `json` rather than `xml` and is necessary for newer MacOS versions, use this template: https://gist.github.com/ijoseph/dd136b7bdf622bbe54f7339db052df5e