# Option + Shift on IntelliJ/Android Studio for Mac OS Yosemite

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, android-studio, shortcut, osx-yosemite

How can I use keymaps that include Option + Shift on IntelliJ/Android for Mac OS Yosemite?
Option + Shift + (Ch) will always return an alternate character, forexample Option + Shift + F will give me ∫ instead of my configured shortcut.

How can I disable that?

Comment: Here is the solution that worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24100077/3664461