# IdeaVim, multi cursor usage

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide, rubymine, ideavim, multiple-cursor

I'm trying to trigger (to use) the IdeaVim multi cursor plugin: https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim#emulated-vim-plugins -> multiple-cursors

In the github docs we have commands: `<A-n>`, `<A-x>`, `<A-p>`, `g<A-n>` to trigger/use this plugin, but I'm not able to make this plugin working at all...

I've added in my .ideavimrc `set multiple-cursors`.

Am I missing something?

I'm using OSX (if that's important).

Comment: does `g<A-n>` work for you? because that doesnt work for me. Right: its "press g" then "press ALT+N". Does the same like doing ALT+N for me

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yeah, tnx for reminding me for that!

Actually, now in OSX Mojave, we can just choose `Unicode Hex Input` in keyboard Input Sources[image]

And that's about it... Now everything is ok and special characters are disabled on (alt/option + ) input, and I can use all the shortcuts without any problem :)

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I prefer it as it requires fewer steps and easily allows me to "restore" the default state if needed.

Comment: Reminder: ~/.ideavimrc should have `set multiple-cursors` .

Comment: Another thing to add, you'll prolly have to make the `unicode hex input` as the only input source -- on macOS Mojave, I had U.S as input source along with this and those special characters still kept popping up for me and the multiple-cursors didn't work :)

Comment: @sidmishraw I think you have to choose the Keyboard type in the menubar after you've added `Unicode Hex Input`.

`Unicode Hex Input` will break some other keyboard shortcuts, most notably for me is the `option-arrow` combinations. I just switch back to `U.S.` when not in Intellij.

Comment: Is it possible to remap the bindings? I would like to use those from plugin, for example
 <C-n> instead of <A-n> for start multicursor and add a virtual cursor + selection on the match.

Comment: Yes, you can remap, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65430514/88374

Comment: This solution is easy, but it also breaks Option+Delete (delete by word) and Option+Left/Right (move caret by word) in most places.

Answer (score 29):

As mentioned in other answers, macOS treats `<A-n>` as a "dead key" in order to enter accented characters, such as `ñ` (`<A-n>n`). It doesn't seem possible to disable this programmatically, and you have to use an alternative keyboard input source to work around this.

However, the `<A-n>` keys are not the keys used by the extension that IdeaVim's `multiple-cursors` is based on ([terryma/vim-multiple-cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors)). I'm not sure where they came from, but vim-multiple-cursors uses `<C-n>`, `<C-p>` and `<C-x>` and only uses `<A-n>` to select all occurrences, which is different to the IdeaVim behaviour. There is an issue tracking the wrong key mappings - [VIM-2178](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-2178).

In the meantime, you can remap the keys to match the Vim plugin by adding the following to your `~/.ideavimrc`:

```
" Remap multiple-cursors shortcuts to match terryma/vim-multiple-cursors
nmap <C-n> <Plug>NextWholeOccurrence
xmap <C-n> <Plug>NextWholeOccurrence
nmap g<C-n> <Plug>NextOccurrence
xmap g<C-n> <Plug>NextOccurrence
xmap <C-x> <Plug>SkipOccurrence
xmap <C-p> <Plug>RemoveOccurrence
```

(**Updated 27/06/2023**: Removed the normal mode mappings for `<C-x>` and `<C-p>` to prevent unexpected characters entered into text)

And you can work around the `<A-n>` issue for "select all occurrences" by mapping to something else, such as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>:

```
" Note that the default <A-n> and g<A-n> shortcuts don't work on Mac due to dead keys.
" <A-n> is used to enter accented text e.g. ñ
nmap <S-C-n> <Plug>AllWholeOccurrences
xmap <S-C-n> <Plug>AllWholeOccurrences
nmap g<S-C-n> <Plug>AllOccurrences
xmap g<S-C-n> <Plug>AllOccurrences
```

Comment: this should be the selected answer

Answer (score 4):

OSX has special characters that are mapped to <kbd>option</kbd>+*key*. You should disable them using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876485/how-to-disable-typing-special-characters-when-pressing-option-key-in-mac-os-x) for example.

After that write this text:

```
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
```

put caret on `Hello` and press `<A-n>` several times. All `Hello` should be selected with a separate caret for each word.

Answer (score 1):

Add caret below or above the line. Using "Shift + Down" and "Shift + Up"

```
nmap <S-Down> :action EditorCloneCaretBelow<CR>
nmap <S-Up> :action EditorCloneCaretAbove<CR>
```