# Mac generating ∆˚¬ characters instead of executing VSCode shortcuts that involve alt / option key

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, key-bindings

**Problem**
When I type `alt+j`, I always get the character `∆`, even if I've assigned `alt+j` to a keyboard shortcut within VSCode.

The same is true for any other alphanumeric keys, but non-character-generating keys work fine with alt, like `alt+upArrow`.

Therefore, I can't use the `alt` key as a modifier for many keyboard shortcuts.

I realize this is normal MacOS behavior for text input, but I'm wondering:

**Question**
Can VSCode override / takes-precedence-over the OS, so that I can use the `alt` key for keyboard shortcuts?

**Tried so far**
I've searched for settings within VSCode and MacOS, but haven't found anything obvious.  I've also edited `keybindings.json`, to no effect.

Comment: Is [How to disable typing special characters when pressing option key in Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876485/how-to-disable-typing-special-characters-when-pressing-option-key-in-mac-os-x) out of date?

Comment: Thanks for that link!  I'd rather rely on native Mac or VSCode options than an 3rd-party intermediary, if possible.

Comment: VS Code is a third-party program w.r.t. the Apple ecosystem, so you've stepped on that path already ;)

Comment: Ah, by 3rd-party, I literally mean that MacOS is (1), VSCode is (2), and I'd rather not have a (3) to keep track of if this can be done within (1) and (2).

Answer (score 27):

Solved this as follows with no complicated keybinding file changes:

⟶ System preferences
⟶ Keyboard
⟶ Input Sources Tab
⟶ `+` at bottom left
⟶ add and select `Unicode Hex Input` from panel on right

✓  Mac no longer prints anything on `alt`+`letter|number`
 ✓  enter unicode characters via  `alt`+`[code]`
 ✅ **Keyboard shortcuts are assignable to alt key!**

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I was on a Mac which had Input Source as ABC-Lang, I removed ABC-Lang and added ABC, and I was able to use VSCode shortcuts.

Comment: The unicode hex option does not exist for me.

Comment: I replaced `ABC` with `Unicode Hex Input` and everything works fine 

Comment: @Brad you have to select 'other' in the list of the languages

Answer (score 5):

```
"terminal.integrated.macOptionIsMeta": true
```

[Source](https://medium.com/@Aenon/use-option-key-as-meta-in-vs-code-d1aad488b40c)

Comment: it only works in terminal but not the editor

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mac and typed 'opt+a/p/9/...' or 'opt+shift+a/q/9..' and then got wired special characters, you find the right place.

I was using [Karabiner](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) and struggled to find the perfect solution. Open you 'karabiner.json' config file. Put the following '**Boss Rule**' in the last position, if you have own binding keys, remember to put your rules before the following rule. Other apps' shortcuts seem to be override by this last rule unless you set application exception, find more about it [here](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/json/complex-modifications-manipulator-definition/conditions/frontmost-application/).

> The manipulators are evaluated from the top to the bottom and the
> input event is manipulated only the first matched manipulator.

```
{
  description: 'disable all option or option+shift keys',
  manipulators: [
    {
      from: {
        any: 'key_code',
        modifiers: {
          mandatory: ['left_option'],
          optional: 'left_shift'
        }
      },
      to: [
        {
          key_code: 'vk_none'
        }
      ],
      type: 'basic'
    }
  ]
}
```

Save the config file and enjoy!!!

Comment: Another option is to exchange your "left_option" and "left_control" using Karabiner and this is the way I am using now. It feels awesome. For shortcuts, I used to set "left_option+j" to move cursor left, but now I set it to "left_control+j". But I am still pressing "left_option" in the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Set your keyboard input source to "ABC", not "ABC - Extended" or anything else and it will work as expected.

Steps:
System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Sources -> + (add an input source) -> Select "ABC"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ABC-India select ABC in System Preferences->Keyboard->System Input -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MZVZ.jpg)

This ✅ solved the issue for me.

Comment: This is already part of the existing Answers.