# Can I customize option key + [in Mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I'm using copilot.

I need to use option + [, to get another suggestions from copilot.

But on my M1 PRO, if I press option + [, ' or " comes out.

Is there any way to modify this?

In order to use other suggestions in copilot, I changed the shortcut corresponding to option + [ in vscode.

option + [ pressing, I get ' or "..

Comment: Can you use `Ctrl+[` ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable generating special characters when pressing the \`alt+a\`/\`option+a\` keybinding in Mac OS (\`⌥+a\` )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876485/how-to-disable-generating-special-characters-when-pressing-the-alta-optiona)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the CoPilot docs, see for Visual Studio Code "[Keyboard shortcuts for GitHub Copilot](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/configuring-github-copilot/configuring-github-copilot-in-visual-studio-code#keyboard-shortcuts-for-github-copilot)". Note the command names.

To customize the key binding in VS Code, open Keyboard Shortcuts (cmd-k cmd-s) and search for `editor.action.inlineSuggest.showNext`, which is the command name for "*Show next inline suggestion*". Double-click to change the key binding.

Comment: It seems OP had done this already. The problem is that he can't assign `editor.action.inlineSuggest.showNext` to `Alt+]`

Comment: Since Apple keyboards don't have an Alt key, it would be hard to assign. But joking aside, yes I did not read the question as "how do I override the macOS keyboard shortcuts for left double quote and left single quote?" Apple phased out the 'alt' label on keyboards about 5 years ago. The Option key is not an Alt key with a different name. The intended use is different. VS Code shouldn't be mapping alt-] and alt-[ to opt-] and opt-[ because those option key combinations are not usable by applications. (I'll update m y answer.)

Answer (score 1):

So `option+]` does not work for me, but `shift+option+]` does, so I have made this keybinding. To open keyboard.json, press `cmd+shift+p` and search for json keyboard.

```json
{
  {
    "key": "shift+alt+[",
    "command": "editor.action.inlineSuggest.showPrevious",
    "when": "inlineSuggestionVisible && !editorReadonly"
  }
}
```

So now I can type

```js
function calculateDaysBetweenDates(begin, end) {
```

trigger suggestion with `option+\`, and use `shift+option+[` or `shift+option+]` to cycle through suggestions.