# vim: can I have the last key of a multi-key binding repeat the command?

Tags: vim

I want to do window resizing in `vim` similarly to how I do it in `tmux`.

With my `tmux` bindings (of the form `bind -r J resize-pane -D 5`, where the `-r` is for repeat) I can do `<C-b>JJJ`, which is the same number of keys and effect as `vim`'s `15<C-w>+`, but much less thinking because I can just move the split until it looks right, rather than deciding a number of rows/cols in advance.

Another example: I want to be able to press `<C-w>++++--`, and have it perform the same action as pressing `<C-w>+<C-w>+<C-w>+<C-w>+<C-w>-<C-w>-`. (Although I'd probably want to remap it again to do 5 lines/cols per move instead of 1).

Is this kind of repeat/timeout mode possible in `vim` bindings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a tricky one, but I'll share my method of handling this, as I think it's even easier than the `<C-w>` methods (which I used for a long time, and found bothersome):

```
" simplify resizing splits
if has('unix')
    nnoremap ^[j <C-w>-
    nnoremap ^[k <C-w>+
    nnoremap ^[h <C-w><
    nnoremap ^[l <C-w>>
else
    nnoremap <M-j> <C-w>-
    nnoremap <M-k> <C-w>+
    nnoremap <M-h> <C-w><
    nnoremap <M-l> <C-w>>
endif
```

The `^[` characters must be replaced by an actual escape. Create it in insert mode by pressing `Ctrl+v`, then `escape`. This was required to use `meta+x` in bash on Linux. Now in both OSes I can just hold `Alt` and the `hjkl` keys to resize splits, including holding down, say, `Alt+h` to horizontally shrink the split I'm in. They also work with counts.

Comment: It's not as general as `tmux` repeat bindings, but still a perfect solution for this use case. Thanks!

Comment: It works for me in Terminator. I had to first disable Alt Key in the config.

Comment: Is there a way to use other keys (like the arrow keys) instead of hjkl?

Comment: @TimPotapov - Yes, replace the `<M-j>` bits with `<Left>`, `<Right>`, `<Up>`, and `<Down>`. For example: `nnoremap <Left> <C-w><`.