# Using Alt key to cycle tabs in vim in terminal

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I am currently using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key to navigate tabs in vim in terminal, like this :

```
noremap <C-Left> :tabprevious<CR>
nnoremap <C-Right> :tabnext<CR>
```

I would like to change from using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key to using <kbd>Alt</kbd> key instead. I tried this :

```
noremap <M-Left> :tabprevious<CR>
nnoremap <M-Right> :tabnext<CR>
```

But, it did not work, I got `E 388: No definition found`

Any suggestions?

Also, What is the <kbd>M</kbd> key in vim? Isn't it <kbd>Alt</kbd>?

Comment: do you use terminal-vim, gvim, macvim or neovim ?
Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501092/can-i-map-alt-key-in-vim

Comment: What's wrong with `gt` and `gT`.

Comment: @romainl you don't find it cumbersome?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo I'm using vim in terminal. I updated the question.

Comment: Would rather go for `gt` and `gT` or else mouse click

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you have another mapping overriding this one. To check, try entering this in the Vim command line:

```
verbose map <M-Left>
```

This should tell you what you have `<M-Left>` mapped to and what file the map was made in.