# Any mapping in vimrc with Alt isn't working

Tags: vim

I have some mappings in my .vimrc with ALT. They are:

```
nnoremap <A-J> :m .+1<CR>==
nnoremap <A-K> :m .-2<CR>==
```

Expected behavior: These two mappings are supposed to move a line up and down. But they are not working. I am not even getting any error or warning. But when I use shift, they are working fine. Below are given the working mappings.

```
nnoremap <A-J> :m .+1<CR>==
nnoremap <A-K> :m .-2<CR>==
```

Why isn't ALT working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501092/can-i-map-alt-key-in-vim

Comment: If it is not too much to ask can anyone explain the answer. I don't get it.

Comment: I am using linux and not mac

Comment: @AlG When I press ALT+j in insert mode, vim goes back to normal mode and the cursor moves down one line

Comment: Eddard: as previously advised, your audience on Stack Overflow generally prefers it if you can keep your questions free of please-help-mes, thanks, advance thanks and other chatty material. Just stick to the detail as much as possible. References [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288160) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776).

Comment: @halfer, I will stick to it in the future. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start by viewing the key code your terminal is sending to vim:

`$ sed -n l`

I am on Ubuntu, and `Alt+j` leads to

`^[j`

This basically prints out the combination of keycodes that is being sent to vim from your terminal.

If you are having difficulties with the `<A+j>` key combination, you can get what  is sending to vim and then use that in the `.vimrc`.

as follows:

`nnoremap ^[j :m .+1<CR>==`

This will map `<Alt + J>` to moving a line up.

**Note:** Don't copy and paste `nnoremap ^[j :m .+1<CR>==` into your .vimrc. You will have to find what keycodes are being sent this in your terminal, and it could be very different from `^[j` as each terminal might send different keycodes to vim. I am using Putty + Ubuntu running on a VM.

Comment: Trying this on Ubuntu under windows using WSL. The keycodes being sent are ^[j and ^[k just like you. however adding the line mentioned in my vimrc does nothing

Comment: yep same experience/problem - also on Ubuntu (WSL2) does not help a bit. 
<Alt+j> still just throws me out eg out of INSERT mode to NORMAL mode but nothing more (eg in NORMAL or VISUAL mode since I also added inoremap and vnoremap))

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, add this to your zsh file

```
alias vim="stty stop '' -ixoff ; vim"
```

This is not necessary but it does get rid of vim mapping issues. Secondly, start by viewing the key code your terminal is sending to vim:

```
$ sed -n l
```

I am on Ubuntu, and Alt+j leads to

```
^[j
```

This basically prints out the combination of keycodes that is being sent to vim from your terminal. Note that the first part `^[` is the `Escape` key and not part of the key pressed.

Add this to your `.vimrc`

```
map <Esc>j <A-j>
```

Afterwards, you can use this to map to other functions:

```
nnoremap <A-j> :m .+1<CR>==
```

Source:
https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Mapping_fast_keycodes_in_terminal_Vim

Comment: Would be nice if someone could explain why

Answer (score 0):

To map Alt you must use M instead of A.

```
nnoremap <M-J> :m .+1<CR>==
nnoremap <J-K> :m .-2<CR>==
```

Comment: In order to trigger this map you need to press Alt+Shift+J  or Alt-Shift-K because we are using capital J and K.