# Vim: remap of cursor movement keys (hjkl) to keys witn Alt (<A-...>) don't work

Tags: vim

I want to remap default cursor movement keys (hjkl) to Colemak's on same places (hnei) + alt, just as described here: https://forum.colemak.com/topic/50-colemak-vim/p6/

This is what was typed to .vimrc (which lies in correct directory, I checked):

```
" Colemak hjkl hack
nnoremap <A-h> <Left>|
nnoremap <A-n> <Down>|
nnoremap <A-e> <Up>|
nnoremap <A-i> <Right>|
```

I have already tried to:

- Remove "|"s
- Switch between  and
- Use hjkl instead of `<Left><Down><Up><Right>`
- Use "noremap" instead of "nnoremap",

Nothing happens. What is wrong?

Comment: Detection of Meta\Alt can be wonky sometimes, maybe that's the problem, see if answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501092/can-i-map-alt-key-in-vim) help.

Comment: You should explain on what OS you are. On Linux in terminal you could try to use `<esc>h` instead of `<A-h>`.

Answer (score 1):

`<esc>h` instead of `<A-h>` works, thanks to [Ralf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7369280/ralf)